# Сокрытие полей в SE Data Explorer

Tags: поддержка, stackexchange, data-explorer

Товарищи, я точно не знаю, можно ли задавать здесь вопросы по данной теме, так что в случае чего - посылайте по адресу :)

---

Итак, у меня возник вопрос следующего характера: почему у объекта `Vote` из таблицы `Votes` сокрыт параметр `UserId`?

То есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT [Votes].[UserId] FROM [Votes] WHERE [Votes].[PostId] = @PostId;
```

возвращает пустую колонку...

Сомневаюсь, что этих данных там правда нет, по сему считаю, что они по какой-то причине скрываются от глаз простых смертных

---

Итак, резюмируя: почему некоторые поля при использовании [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) **сокрыты**, хотя они и объявлены?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что Data Explorer - не легкий способ обхода ограничений на доступ к данным. Через него доступно только то, что доступно и на основном сайте. Голоса анонимны (кроме "добавление в избранное" и "принятие ответа") - поэтому пользователя для них нету.

Comment: Так-то логично, но зачем тогда вообще это поле для `Data Explorer`’a, если оно всегда будет пустым? Или, скажем, модераторам и прочим подобным гражданам таковые данные доступны?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov скорее всего, «прочим подобным» видны. Проще, видимо, сокрыть данные, нежели менять структуру.

Answer (score 7):

Votes - это не только голоса за/против, но и ["добавление в избранное"](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/880366/favs), и "назначение награды", и еще много других типов "голосов", перечисленных в `VoteTypes`.

Для тех голосов, данные о которых находятся в открытом доступе, UserID доступен. Для тех, данные к которых видны только самому участнику или CM/модераторам - UserID скрыт.